# Suspicious SSL certificate

Tags: broadcom, ssl

I have a Lenovo E330 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. Sometimes the certificate in this picture:

[image: picture]

Prompts me when I start up the computer, and I find it looks quite suspicious.

Can anybody tell me why it's prompting me for accepting this SSL certificate and if there is a way to stop it. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your router's configuration.

I recently changed ISP and the router from the new ISP has "Daniel's" SSL certificate for the router's HTTPS management web page. This router is a Zyxel VMG1312; I don't know which other makes/models of routers have been blessed with "Daniel's" self-signed certificates.

I also can't explain why Daniel thinks California is in Ukraine (UA) instead of America (US). Possibly a typo, since "a" is next to "s" on many keyboards.

Elsewhere in the router's admin pages is an option to install my own SSL certificates; I may investigate that later on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Alex. My router is a Zyxel VMG1312, so I'm pretty sure that hits the nail on the head :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this certificate looks suspicious. It might be that somebody is messing with your network and trying man-in-the-middle attacks. Please check if other hosts in the network are affected too.

If no other host is affected try to find out when exactly you get this message, that is which host gets accessed in this case. It might also be that there is a router or similar device in your network with an expired certificate and for whatever reason you are trying to access this host.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @v2r I suppose you picked the wrong template - this seems to answer the question.

Comment: @gruntbert - no I've changed the answer to be more specific.

Comment: If it is someone trying a man-in-the-middle attack wouldn't they try with a less suspicious looking certificate than one Daniel issued for a month in 2006?

I will keep an eye out and return in a couple of days. 
Im new to AskUbuntu - is it okay to wait with choosing the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is the SSL certificate installed by default on ZyXEL VMG1312 routers, I know because mine has the same certificate. It looks like your computer is attempting to communicate with your router using an encrypted protocol (like SSH or HTTPS) and is warning you that the certificate is invalid.

The certificate expired in 2006 so there's no way to trust it. This leaves you with 2 options:

1, stop communicating with your router via secure protocols. The downside here is that you're removing a level of security, however on your LAN it isn't as important as if you were accessing your router over the internet.

2, replace the certificate on the router with an in-date cert signed by a Certificate Authority that your computer trusts (by this I mean if you're going down the self-signed route you need to add the router as a trusted CA). This is the preferred route but requires an understand of SSL security certificates and their management, and also that you know how to replace the cert on your router. I've just started looking at this now so when I find the location of the cert I'll reply with steps.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct in that the HTTPS certificate in a Zyxel VMG1312 router is the root cause.

**Why?** Any connections made outbound from the connected client while the router is rebooting or the WAN link is down get hijacked by the router and handled by itself instead of the web, including HTTP, HTTP, and SSH traffic.

This means webapps like Facebook that make repeated connections will trigger the prompt, and SSH connections trigger the "remote key changed" warning.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: @tim It wasn't a new question. It is extra information that wasn't mentioned by the other answers.

Comment: I think it should be a comment then

Comment: @Tim Thank you, but I don't. It was an answer as to why the OP could have seen it, and didn't directly relate to any of the other answers given. Would you consider removing the downvote?

Comment: Then probably you can comment it directly below the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Ron It does, it confirms it's a Zyxel router and exactly which situations it will appear and why. What more could you want from an answer?